# OnCell change event write to next sheet vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBMacro. I have 3 columns in spreadsheet. `Partnumber, description, Net value`. I have a list selection(`Two values:1, Empty`) in particular cells. 
When I select '1' the Partnumber, Description should written in another tab of same spreadsheet.

How can i achieve this? on worksheet change event it will be effective?

Comment: You have good rep and you gave already many good answers. Would you imagine for a second that you have to answer a question formulated like this?

Comment: Same as @A.S.H ! BTW, why not use a `Vlookup`?

Comment: We understand your **requirement**, but what is your **question** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Column = 7) Then 
        Dim cquote As Worksheet

        Set cquote = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyQuote")


        Select Case (Target.Value)
            Case "1":           

                Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CQuote")
                NextRow = wsMaster.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1              

                cquote.Cells(NextRow, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
                cquote.Cells(NextRow, 2).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value
                cquote.Cells(NextRow, 5).NumberFormat = "@"
                cquote.Cells(NextRow, 5).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value
            Case " ":
                Dim existCQrange As Range

                Set existCQrange = cquote.Range("B1:B1048576").Find(Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value)

                If (existCQrange Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
                cquote.Rows(existCQrange.Row).EntireRow.Delete (True)
        End Select

    End If
End Sub
```